# Is it possible to "group" build configurations in TeamCity to share dependencies?

Tags: teamcity

I have a project with the folloging build configuration: build, mediumTests, largeTests, deploy. Dependencies are like this:

```
    build  <--  mediumTests  <--  deploy
       ^------  largeTests <--------|
```

(I hope this graphic and the following description is understandable)

Now, to ease configuration, I would like to combine the configurations mediumTests and largeTests into a test configuration group, so that my deploy job only has one dependency (to the "test" group). Is that possible?

Comment: You might be able to do what you want with templates https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Build+Configuration+Template - please add more information if this doesn't help

Comment: Good idea, this is half of a solution. Templates solve the "left side dependency", as all test configurations inherit the dependency to the build config. But they don't work for the right side, as you cannot add a snapshot dependency to-> a template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to use Composite(aggregator) configuration.

Test Aggregator will depend on medium Tests and Large Tests.

Deploy will depend on Test Aggregator.

Build <- Tests Aggregator <- Deploy

This solution works for me